# Looping from JSON file with Jquery $.each

Tags: jquery, json, each

I have a fairly large JSON file and I wish to loop through certain keys with Jquery.

How would I use a variable ( "countrySelector" in the example below) in my $.each loop so I only filter through the relevant key/selector.

Here is my JSON layout

```
{ - world_projects: {
    - australia: {
        - {
            project_id: 123
          },
        - {
            project_id: 456
          },
    },
    - usa: {
        - {
            project_id: 789
          },
        - {
            project_id: 022
          },
    },
}
```

Here is my Jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Grab the country
    var countrySelector = $( '#map-projects-wrapper' ).data('country');

    // Get our JSON file which contains all collections
    // and project information
    $.getJSON( "projects.json", function( jsonData ) {

        // Cycle through each Project
        $.each( jsonData.world_projects.countrySelector, function( project_key, projects ) {
            // here I would do my thing
        }
    }
});
```

I hope that makes sense,

Thank you
Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`countrySelector` is not a property, it is a variable holding the key name so you need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) as the [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

```
jsonData.world_projects[countrySelector]
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, that's perfect! :)